# Remove tooltips Symfony 6

Tags: forms, symfony6

I'm new to symfony 6: here's my "problem": how do I remove the tooltips from the photo with symfony so that I can customise it myself on the web page? Thanks in advance.

I've tested constraints and invalid_message but I'm ready to take on any help I can get thanks .[enter image description [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNc5N.png)here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSoYG.png)

Comment: you are probably referring to HTML5 native form validation. To disable it you would need to add a `novalidate` attribute to your form. Check https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#client-side-html-validation